# Move a dataframe column to last column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, shift

I want move the column in a dataframe to last column, I tried
using `shift`. But this doesn't change the position.

```
import pandas a pd
df = #input dataframe
df['x'] = df['x'].shift(axis=1)
```

```
Error:
    raise ValueError(f"No axis named {axis} for object type {cls.__name__}")
ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type Series
```

Are there other options? Could someone please suggest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [`pop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) and insert again:

```
df['X'] = df.pop('X')
```

example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([list('axbc')], columns=['A', 'X', 'B', 'C'])
print(df)

   A  X  B  C
0  a  x  b  c


df['X'] = df.pop('X')
print(df)

   A  B  C  X
0  a  b  c  x
```

Another, more generic, option would be to reindex, for this you can remove the columns to move last from the index and add them in the end. The advantage is that you can handle many columns at once and chose to more to different spots:

```
to_move = ['X']
new = df.columns.difference(to_move).to_list()+to_move
# ['A', 'B', 'C', 'X']

df = df[new]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the columns into "end_cols" and "other_cols" and pass them back to the selector -

```py
# Borrowing @mozway's df
end_col = ['X'] 
other_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col not in end_col]
df[other_cols + end_col]
```

**Output**

```
   A  B  C  X
0  a  b  c  x
```

Comment: You have to be careful: `[col for col in df.columns if col not in end_col]` has quadratic complexity (O(n*m) with n the length of `end_col` and m the length of `other_col`), this is not efficient if `end_col` is large. In contrast `df.columns.difference` is linear.

Comment: We should probably modify it to `[col for col in df.columns if col not in set(end_col)]` when `end_col` is large

Comment: the set definition should be outside of the list comprehension, else you define it every time ;)

Comment: That's interesting, Thanks! I would have assumed that the python interpreter would optimize for that, but I guess you are right, especially given that both `set` and `list` are mutable.